# How to assign a radiobuttonlist to a boundfield in GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, sqldatasource

I imported an excel table consisting of 5 columns and 50 rows into a datatable and stored it in a database table. None of the columns are a primary key as they consist data of string, are repetitive and even allow null values.

Eg:

**EmpID | EmpName | Desig | Dept | Gender**

are the columns in my table.

I create a DataGrid with a SqlDataSource and Bind the data from the DB Table to the GridView using Bound Fields.

Eg:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="EmpID" HeaderText="Employee ID" SortExpression="EmpID"/>

<asp:BoundField DataField="EmpName" HeaderText="Employee Name" SortExpression="EmpName"/

<asp:BoundField DataField="Desig" HeaderText="Designation" SortExpression="Desig"/>

<asp:BoundField DataField="Dept" HeaderText="Department" SortExpression="Dept"/>

<asp:BoundField DataField="Gender" HeaderText="Gender" SortExpression="Gender"/>
```

Rows in the **Gender** column are completely null while others have some data into them.

I need to insert a RadioButtonList in specific rows of the Gender column in the GridView which satisfy the condition of rows/cells in the EmpID column starting with the letter 'A'

Eg:

[image: Table]

Also, on selecting the respective radiobutton, its value must be updated in the database table.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: This won't be possible with a boundfield. Is there any reason it must be a boundfield?

Comment: I get that it's possible only with a TemplateField. But without using BoundField, How do I bind "Gender" column alone with the Database Table through the datasource?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use TemplateColumn instead.